# Путь к папке для хранения файлов приложения. Xamarin Android

Tags: android, c#, файлы, xamarin

Я знаю, что у андройд приложений есть папка, к которой имеет доступ только само приложение и система. Она удаляется вместе с приложением. Хочу поместить туда json файл с настройками приложения. Как получить путь к этой папке в Xamarin Android?

Comment: [Android.Content.ContextWrapper.FilesDir Property](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Android.Content.ContextWrapper.FilesDir/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно вам нужен этот путь :
ExternalStorage
     `var path =global::Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath;`

InternalStorage

```
string path = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
```

Comment: Это путь к корню хранилища, а мне нужен путь к папке, в которой хранятся данные приложения, и которая удаляется вместе с приложением.

Comment: У моего приложения почему-то нет прав на добавления файлов в папке по пути InternalStorage. Подскажите пожалуйста, какие права нужны для этого приложению?

Comment: InternalStorage доступен для приложения без каких либо разрешений. А вы используете эмулятор или реальное устройство ?

Comment: Все заработало, я неправильно добавлял путь к конкретному файлу. Спасибо вам большое за помощь