# Как прочитать json файл лежащий в общем проекте?

Tags: c#, json, xamarin

Есть общий проект (`.NET Standard`). В нём лежит файл `User.json` с информацией о пользователях.
Нужно в этом проекте создать статический класс, к которому мы будем обращаться из платформозависимых проектов и получать информацию из файла.
 Как получить из него данные в этом же `.NET Standard` проекте?

Вот скриншот структуры проекта и расположения файла в нём:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код Класса MainActivity:

```
namespace emailsender_standard.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "emailsender_standard", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@mipmap/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        Button sendBtn = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.SendBtn);
        sendBtn.Click += Button_Click;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        EditText email = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.email);
        EditText subject = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.subject);
        EditText bodyText = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.bodyText);

        if (Validation.IsValid(email.Text, subject.Text, bodyText.Text))
        {
            //work with file in Andoid Project
            StreamReader strm = new StreamReader(Assets.Open("AndroidUsers.json"));
            string response = strm.ReadToEnd();

            var users = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<User>>(response);

            //TODO: work with file in NETStandard project
        }
        else
        {
            ShowAlert("Validation error", "Fill in all gaps and check e-mail");

}
    }

    void ShowAlert(string title, string message)
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        AlertDialog alert = dialog.Create();
        alert.SetTitle(title);
        alert.SetMessage(message);
        alert.SetButton("OK", (c, ev) =>
        {
            // Ok button click task  
        });
        alert.Show();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: В .NET Standard можно использовать библиотеку [JSON.NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/10.0.3).

Comment: это я знаю, но я не совсем понял как её правильно использовать

Comment: Вам не кажется что Вы все тут с расположением объектов перепутали?  или неправильно описали где что лежит. 
Сначала идет сага о том, что ваш файл JSON лежит в общем проекте, потом Вы приводите код для получения файла из специальной папки платформы. Если нужен в Core(общий) проекте тогда опубликую сейчас пример.

Comment: @a.tarasevich Вы привели код андройда. Вам нужен код в общем проекте.

Comment: @Dev так в общем проекте расположен пустой класс, т.к. мне с самого начала нужно решить проблему доступа к файлу, а решение данной проблемы меня и интересует

Comment: @a.tarasevich просто вопрос. почему вы хотите положить общий файл в общий проект и писать логику доступа для каждой платформы?

Comment: @a.tarasevich у Вас есть общий проект, общий файл, концепция общего доступа. так и реализуйте чтение файла один раз в общем проекте и полученные данные из файла можете передать как обуйте С# UI элементами(платформам андройд и IOs)

Comment: @Dev файл - одинаковый для всех. Логика чтения из файла и занесение данных в модель, я думаю, тоже одинаковая. Следовательно зачем копипастить одинаковый код на все проекты?

Comment: @a.tarasevich ну так и реализуйте мой ответ в общем проекте

Comment: @Dev так в этом же и вопрос, как мне прочитать файл

Comment: @Dev testXamarinPage - получается страничка UI насколько я понял? если так, то у нас нету доступа из общего проекта к платформазависимым проектам

Comment: @a.tarasevich вы не пометили что это Forms или Nativ проект. отсюда и название класса. Концепт как я и писал в комментарии к ответу таков: создаете класс в общем проекте и пишите в нем код из ответа. testXamarinPage имя класса, где вы пишите эту логику чтения. testXamarin имя сборки

Comment: @Dev спасибо огромное, извините за потраченное мною ваше время! Всего наилучшего вам!

Comment: @a.tarasevich не за что. помогайте другим так же с большим терпением ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var assembly = typeof(testXamarinPage).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("testXamarin.MyJson.json");
using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream))
{
  var text = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

MyJson.json это Ваш файл. его нужно пометить в свойствах как "EmbeddedResource" там же в свойствах найдете его ID (testXamarin.MyJson.json)
testXamarin это им проекта и его имя сборки.

Comment: не совсем понял где найти ID файла и что такое testXamarin. Прикрепил скриншот размещения файла и структуры проекта.

Comment: @a.tarasevich значит у VS для Windows нет такого меню. 
"testXamarin это им проекта и его имя сборки." namespace Вам что-то говорит? это (зачастую) имя сборки. Возможно в Вашем примере это будет emailsender_standard. и ID ресурса будет emailsender_standard.Users.json

Comment: если в первой строчке вашего ответа вместо "testXamarinPage" поставить "emailsender_standard", тогда подчеркивает и пишет 'emailsender_standard is a namespace but used like a type'

Comment: @a.tarasevich Ок. что значит Page? думаю это какая-то страница (UI). значит что тут нужно поставить? правильно, имя текущего класса. Что это даст? Через рефлексию получите ссылку на сборку и все файлы сборки. Что это значит? не пытайтесь бездумно копипастить и анализируете всю работу. testXamarin Это имя сборки(проекта в текущем примере так же) testXamarinPage имя текущего класса где я танцую с бубном вокруг JSON файла.

Comment: assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("testXamarin.MyJson.json"); возвращает null

Comment: @a.tarasevich пишите весь код класса в вопросе. Покажу что и как должно быть в Вашем примере.

Comment: спасибо. Код добавил

Answer (score 0):

Пример с использованием Newtonsoft библиотеки

```
UserModel userModel = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserModel> (System.IO.File.ReadAllText("YOUR_FILE_PATH\User.json"));
```

Если нужно будет узнать путь , то я уже давал ответ на подобный вопрос [ССЫЛКА](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/706197/%D0%9F%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-xamarin-android/706257#706257)

Пример с парсингом из Json в string. Не знаю правда  зачем вам это)

```
JObject jsonObject = JObject.Parse(System.IO.File.ReadAllText("YOUR_FILE_PATH\User.json"));
var jsonString = jsonObject.ToString(Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None);
```

Comment: а можно как-то в строку для начала? а не стразу в объект (просто чтобы убедиться что мы получаем данные). Просто почему-то null приходит

Comment: Видимо неправильный путь указан.

Comment: обновил вопрос, посмотрите пожалуйста

Comment: Попробуйте выполнить что-то вроде такого var file = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("YOUR_FILE_PATH\User.json"); И посмотреть file == null или нет)

Comment: пустая строка - ""

Comment: Тогда посмотрите точно ли у вас правильно работает метод получения пути , и есть ли по пути path  - файл.

Comment: var file1 = System.IO.File.Exists(pathToFile); - выдаёт true

Comment: Тогда string file = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("YOUR_FILE_PATH\User.json"); Не должно возвращать "" , а есть ли информация в этом файле) ?

Comment: да,  конечно есть)

Comment: Честно сказать сложно тогда понять в чём дело , без проекта. Могу разве что предложить гайд https://diptimayapatra.wordpress.com/2013/07/05/xamarin-parse-json-text-from-sd-card-in-android/